# USB-SERIAL-FOR-ANDROID it displaying 0 device found

Tags: android, usb

I have installed USB_SERIAL_FOR android project from link 
https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/wiki/CompatibleSerialDevices

I have attached the OTG wire and connect with other USB devices. But this app is not working , it still displaying 0 device found error.

Please help how can I display the devices from this USB application.

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Comment: @AthiraSanthosh from this link only I have downloaded.

Comment: Then it may be your android device is not supported.. There is no guarantee this app will work for all the android devices..

Comment: Check your mobile device manufacture site whether OTG functionality supported or not.. OTG should be supported by hardware funtionality..

Comment: @Brendon, I have checked in different models' these are supporting OTG  cable. But I and not able to display by this application

Comment: have u ever tested the sample application provided with that library?

Comment: No this is first time, But I am not able to see any connected device. I am using new model of Sony C5302, android version 4.1.2